# Serialize immutable classes in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, immutability

I need to return object from client which is immutable by design (contains only public final fields). In GWT, looks like this is not possible?

I created successor of ImageMetadata_CustomFieldSerializer and override methods:

```
- instantiateInstance
- serialize
```

but still my final objects are not initialized (default constructor is invoked)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the CustomFieldSerializer must contain special static methods in order to work properly.

Then special static methods need to be added:

```
public static void deserialize(SerializationStreamReader streamReader, MyObject instance) throws SerializationException {
    //...
}

public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter streamWriter, MyObject instance) throws SerializationException {
   //...
}

public static MyObject instantiate(SerializationStreamReader streamReader) throws SerializationException {
   //...
}
```

these methods contain code to serialize/deserialize MyObject from SerializationStream.

and in overridden methods it is possible to re-use the static ones.

Hope that helps.